# How to relate two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have created two collections ***vendor and employee*** and **vendor collection has references of employee "*emplyoee_id:[String]*"** 
Should I do also vice versa? is that good idea? adding reference in both collections?

what If I want all employees with their company name along with it? I am confused.

> employee

```
const employeeSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  address: String,
  email: String,
  designation: String,
  contact_number: Number,
  contract_start: Date,
  contract_end: Date
});
```

Vendor

```
const vendorSchema = Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    email: [String],
    contact_number: [Number],
    contract_start: Date,
    contract_end: Date,
    emplyoee_id:[String]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a mongoose model you can define properties with a reference to another model. Check mongoose [popolate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks, you redirected me to a correct path and saved my hours +1

Answer (score 0):

For loopback Framework

I have done it with Loopback framework. For example User collection and Project collection has taken For each user, there can be multiple projects and each project has one and only one user.

In project model

```
"relations": {
   "user": {
   "type": "belongsTo",
   "model": "user",
   "foreignKey": "id"
}}
```

In user Model

```
"relations": {
  "projects": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "project",
  "foreignKey": "project_user_id"
}}
```